# check if table exists, using a connection object in java

Tags: java, sql-server, database, oracle, db2

I need to check if a table with a specific "tablename" exists in a database from my java program.

The database may be of different type, viz. MS SQL Server, Oracle, DB2. I have a connection object to the database. Is there a single method that can work for all the types of databases?
I might have to extend the java program to support more db Types, thus a single approach for all DB types would be very much helpful.

The code that I am using.  This appears to work correctly against a SQL Server database but does not find the table in Oracle or DB2

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData(); 
ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, "TABLE_NAME", null); 
if(!res.next()){ 
  //table does not exist. 
} else{
   //table exists. 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simplistic:

```
SELECT
    1
FROM
    TABLE
;
```

If it throws an exception the table does not exist (or something else is wrong).
Otherwise:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: I've tried using DatabaseMetaData class, it works fine for MS SQL Server, but not for Oracle and DB2.

Query that you mentioned will not work with all the DB Types. I'll have to switch-case it for different DB Types.

Comment: if the select 1 is a problem for some DB type then use select count(*) from your_table; this should be supported by all

Comment: or better: select * from your_table where 1 = 0

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DatabaseMetaData.getTables()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) procedure to search the database for tables with a particular pattern.  If you search for an exact name, you'll either get an empty `ResultSet` or a `ResultSet` with a single row telling you that the table exists.

This works for me against an Oracle database whether the table is owned by the current user or a different user.

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
public class TableExists
{
 public static String exists(String tableName)
     throws SQLException
 {
    Connection       conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
    DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData(); 
    ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, tableName, null); 
    if(!res.next()){ 
      return "Nope";
    } else{
      return "Yup";
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that.
It works fine for MS SQL Server, but not for Oracle or DB2

Comment: @ShubhamMaheshwari - Can you help us out by posting the code and telling us exactly what "doesn't work"?  I can tell you that `getTables` most certainly works for Oracle-- I have to assume that you are passing the parameters incorrectly but it is hard to guess what the mistake is without seeing the code.

Comment: `DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();`
`ResultSet res = meta.getTables(null, null, "TABLE_NAME", null);`
`if(!res.next()){`
` //table does not exist.`
`} else{`
` //table exists.`
`}`

Comment: @ShubhamMaheshwari - I edited your question to include the code.  I'm guessing that "doesn't work" means that it tells you that the table doesn't exist when you believe it does.  Please edit the question further if that guess is incorrect.

Comment: yes, in Oracle, it says that the table doesn't exist when it actually does.

Comment: @ShubhamMaheshwari - That code works for me against my Oracle database.  Can you edit your question to post a query against `ALL_TABLES` showing that a particular table exists and the equivalent Java call that doesn't indicate the table exists?  My guess is either that the user you are logging in as doesn't have access to the table or that you are passing in the wrong table name (for example, using the wrong case).

Comment: I am able to access the same table by logging via SQLPlus, using the same user as used while creating the connection object. and I have also double checked the name/case of the tablename.

I could not the first part of your comment "Can you edit your question to post a query against ALL_TABLES showing that a particular table exists and the equivalent Java call that doesn't indicate the table exists?"

Comment: @ShubhamMaheshwari - Edit your question to have something like `select count(*) from all_tables where table_name = 'EMP'` (or whatever table you're interested in) that shows that the table exists and you have access to it.  Then show us the equivalent call to `getTables`.

Comment: I believe that for oracle you need to supply the schema_name when you execute findTables.

Comment: @TheStijn - As long as you pass in `null`, rather than the empty string, you don't need to specify a `schema_name`.  The code I posted works against an 11.2 database (and should work against earlier versions as well) whether the table is owned by the current user or not so long as the user has access to the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `getTables()` method of `DatabaseMetaData`.

Comment: I've tried using DatabaseMetaData class,
it works fine for MS SQL Server, but not for Oracle and DB2

Comment: In the past, I've used the DatabaseMetaData class with MSSQL and Oracle, and it worked fine for me.  Explain your problem.

Comment: @StephenC - Please check the updated question for more info on the problem.

Comment: This method worked for me on some Oracle DBs, but not on others, listing all the tables specifying "%" as table name in some Oracle instances i get an empty resultset, it may have something to do with user privileges but i still haven't figured out what..